# Data folder location incorrect Sitecore 8.2 Update 1

Tags: sitecore

As per Sitecore documentation with version 8.2 rev.161115 the data folder has been relocated to be under website/App_Data folder of the installation.

I installed the vanilla Sitecore installation of Sitecore XP 8.2 rev. 161115 (8.2 Update-1) through the exe web application installer. However in the fresh installation, I noticed that the data folder is still located outside root of my application. The [iis](/questions/tagged/iis) instance and databases were correctly configured by the web installer though.

Is this the expected behavior? As the exe just runs a wizard I don't see an option to configure the default data folder.

Thanks,

Abhi

Comment: AFAIK, it's only been moved for Azure PaaS configuration. For local or regular VM it is unchanged and still outside website folder.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. That's what I was missing :)

Comment: @jammykam how do I mark your comment as answered?

Comment: Let me add a proper answer tomorrow. I'll see if I can dig out some documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are installing Sitecore from the exe or the zip file then the data folder is still located outside from the root application:

From section **4.1 Installation Process Overview** in the [installation guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_82_Update1.aspx):

> 3. Extract the .zip archive to create the following folders:
>
>    - *C:\InetPub\wwwroot\ProjectName\Website*
>    - *C:\InetPub\wwwroot\ProjectName\Data*
>    - *C:\InetPub\wwwroot\ProjectName\Databases*

If you check the structure of the zip package then you will see the same structure:

[image: Sitecore Zip Folder Structure]

The `data` folder has however been moved inside the **website/App_Data** folder for Azure PaaS installation, which makes sense given the nature of AppService containers and the fact that the application is essentially deployed to the root (so folders cannot reside outside). If you check the structure of the packages for Azure AppService from the Sitecore download page then you will notice the same:

[image: Sitecore Azure AppService Folder Structure]

Comment: Thank you so much its clearly explained. However my connecting question would be if I can configure the Azure Pass installation to local IIS. It throws the data folder error.  As its a separate topic I kept the post separate  -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577658/error-configuring-web-root-of-sitecore-wdp-package-in-local-iis-instance